# Assign numeric values to strings based on alphabetical order in R

Tags: r, rank

I would like to create a numeric column in my data frame where the numbers represent the alphabetical order of the strings in a character column.

So let's say I create the following data frame:

df <- data.frame (names  = c("Frank", "Jack", "Peter"))

How do I add a new column where Frank gets the value 1, Jack 2 and Peter 3 (based on the alphabetical order of the names)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rank()` for this:

```
df$alpha_order = rank(df$names)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect for the example mentioned in the OP, which I now see is too simplified because the real use case includes a lot of duplicate names. So even though Frank is mentioned several times, I want all rows with the 'Frank' value to get the value 1.

Comment: The base `rank()` function takes a `ties.method` argument - see the help page `?rank` for details. You can try `rank(df$name, ties.method = "min")` which will mark all ties with the minimum rank. It will leave gaps following ties, e.g., `"Adam", "Adam", "Adam", "Bob"` will get `1, 1, 3`. If you want that to be `1, 1, 2`, use `dplyr::dense_rank` instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `factor` with `as.integer`.  `factor` converts the column to `factor` with default `levels` in the alphabetical order and `as.integer` coerces the levels to integer storage values starting from 1

```
df$alpha_order <- as.integer(factor(df$names))
```